# Node.JS bootstrap 404 trying to get dist/js/login

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I have a webapp running on my local machine. In an HTML file, I have a script src as `/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`. I have set up a route in my `Routes.js` file to handle this request and return the correct file (bootstrap.js).

However, after setting up the route, I'm getting a `404` error on

`/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/login`

I tried setting up a route on this exact call to see if I couldn't get some information about it, but I was hit with a error:

```
Too many redirects
```

I have bootstrap installed through NPM, and my app is able to load all the other bootstrap resources in the folder.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The only code that I can see that is relevant are two pieces. The first is that the html file in question is within `project_root/public/html/index.html` and the bootstrap folder is in `project_root/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`
The second is that the line that is causing the 404 is `<script src='/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'></script>`

I'm just not sure why that html line is looking for "login"

Edit 2: Stupid mistake on my part. I didn't have the route available without authentication. Sorry!

Comment: Will you provide the code?

Comment: if you used express server i think u need to use express.static('node_modules'); function although this is bad habbit to store your frontend css and javascript file in node_modules folder ..

Comment: Scott - did you find my answer helpful. If os, please can you upvote or mark it as the answer. :)  If you are still having trouble let me know.

Comment: All - Thanks for your responses. I will be able to add to this later today.

YLS - I'm using Hapi, but this is just a static HTML page.

Arcseldon - I don't see the difference between referencing the file from within node_modules vs some other folder. Could you offer some more information about the difference here?

Answer (score 0):

You ordinarily wouldn't try to reference your dependencies from within the node_modules folder. Rather, you would have some kind of build process which copies (and optionally does other tasks like uglification / minification) to a folder within your web application server - usually a public directory etc. You would then reference the contents of that public folder from your HTML page instead.

Unclear what your setup is, can you offer more information? Which webserver etc etc.